# Compute type fixed point

Tags: typescript, functor, fixpoint-combinators

Suppose we have some type-function `F<T>`, and we want to compute its fixed point `type X = F<X>`. While this might work with types that are objects

```js
interface Tree1<T> { left: T; right: T }
interface Tree extends Tree1<Tree> {}
declare const t: Tree;
const r = t.left.right; // OK
```

for more generic type-functions it doesn't:

```js
type Tree1<T> = null | { left: T; right: T }
interface Tree extends Tree1<Tree> {} // can't extend not-object
```

Without a deferred type-level computation given by `interface`, it's hard to avoid infinite instantiation. The best I could do is just delay it:

```js
interface Tree1<T> { left: T; right: T }
type Temp1<T> = { a: null | [T[keyof T], T[keyof T]] }
interface Temp2 extends Temp1<Temp2> {}
declare const t: Temp2;
const r = t.a; // Type instantiation is excessively deep
```

Also it is possible to fix it by introducing extraneous nodes into the tree, but that's not what I'm after.

```js
type Tree1<T> = null | { left: T; right: T }
type Tree = Tree1<{ref: Tree}> // OK
```

Neither is directly defining `Tree`.

```js
type Tree = null | { left: Tree, right: Tree }
```

**How to compute that elusive fixed point?**

```js
type Tree1<T> = null | { left: T; right: T }
type Tree = ???
const t: Tree = {left: null, right: {left: null, right: null}};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking because `type Tree<T> = null | { left: T | Tree<T>; right: T | Tree<T>; };` seems to work correctly.

Comment: @hittingonme Okay, I'll add this trivial option to the list of "not what is asked" things to avoid confusion.

Comment: TS has circularity/regress detection and some recursive types are not allowed, so there's no one-size-fits all approach to this.  I don't quite get why you want this, though; it's not like TS has support for higher kinded types, so even if there were such an approach, you'd have to manually apply it every time you wanted to use it.  (You can't even write a single nesting like `type Nest<F<~>, T> = F<F<T>>`, so `type Fix<F<~>> = ...` is hopeless.)  Since manual twiddling is required, I don't understand why you're opposed to the extra twiddling of `type Tree = null | { left: Tree, right: Tree }`

Comment: What is the actual underlying use case or goal here?  Is it an academic exercise?

Comment: 1. `interface Fn { a: unknown; r: unknown }; type Call<F extends Fn, X> = (F & {a: X})["r"]` 2. `type Nest<F extends Fn, T> = Call<F, Call<F, T>>` 3. `interface Test { a: unknown; r: this['a'][]; }; type R = Nest<1>; // 1[][]`.

Comment: Directly represented `Tree` somehow doesn't cause "type instantiation" error, so I don't think it's either disallowed or has to cause instantiation errors.

Comment: I have an API that, given `(f: F<A>) => A` and `(f: G<A>) => A` (for exact `F` and `G`) returns `type FG = F<G<FG>>`. There's no HKTs involved. The `FG` is unrepresentable, because `F` and `G` are unions.

Comment: Well, it's enough to spread one of the unions `type FG = F1<G<FG>> | F2<G<FG>>` and ensure all `F#` are either interfaces or types of bounded size. That works, but such approach is beyond ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to create a literal fixed point of a type function, but you can construct type that refers to itself indirectly through a property.   Depending on what you're using it for, that might be good enough.

I came to your question because I've been thinking about how to type abstract syntax trees.    Specifically, I want an to type ASTs for a related family of languages.   For example, we could have a type for expressions involving adding variables together, like "a + b + c", and we could have another type for expression involving variables, addition, and multiplication, such as "a*b + c".

I want these to be real static types — I don't want to just use one big AST type to rule them all.   But I also want the types to be extendable.  I don't want to have to re-define the whole grammar every time I add some new type of AST node.

So I was thinking, if you could have a generic parameter that corresponds to the language variant, you could define AST nodes like this:

```
type Plus<α extends Grammer> = { 
    kind: "plus"
    left: Expr<α>
    right: Expr<α>
}
```

Then you can define a generic version of the grammar like this:

```
type AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<α extends Grammer> = Variable<α> | Plus<α>
```

And turn it into a monotype by constructing a fixed point

```
AbelianGroupGrammer = AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<AbelianGroupGrammer>
```

You could extend it to larger languages like so

```
type RingBaseGrammar<α extends Grammer> = AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<α> | Times<α>
```

This doesn't work in typescript, You'll get the error `Type alias 'AbelianGroupGrammer' circularly references itself`

But if you hide the self-reference inside an object property, you can get the same effect.   This version does type check without errors:

```
type Grammer = {
    "expression": unknown
}

type Expr<α extends Grammer> = α["expression"]

type Plus<α extends Grammer> = { 
    kind: "plus"
    left: Expr<α>
    right: Expr<α>
}

type Times<α extends Grammer> = { 
    kind: "times"
    left: Expr<α>
    right: Expr<α>
}

type Variable<α> = { 
    kind: "variable"
    name: string
}

type AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<α extends Grammer> = { 
    "expression": Variable<α> | Plus<α>
}

type AbelianGroupGrammer = { 
    "expression": Expr<AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<AbelianGroupGrammer>>
}

type RingBaseGrammer<α extends Grammer> = { 
    "expression": Expr<AbelianGroupBaseGrammer<α>> | Times<α>
}

type RingGrammer = {
    "expression": Expr<RingBaseGrammer<RingGrammer>>
}

const x : Expr<AbelianGroupGrammer> = {kind: "variable", name: "x"}
const y : Expr<AbelianGroupGrammer> = {kind: "variable", name: "y"}
const x_plus_y : Expr<AbelianGroupGrammer> = {kind:"plus", left: x, right: y}
const x_times_x_plus_y : Expr<RingGrammer> = {kind:"times", left: x, right: x_plus_y}

function group2ring(a : Expr<AbelianGroupGrammer>) : Expr<RingGrammer> { 
    return a
}
```